# C# RegEx Match Pattern Exactly

Tags: c#, regex

I'm wanting to match a string exactly, for instance I have two expressions that I want
to match independent of each other.  Expressions are

```
/SignUpFor

/SignUpFor/ThankYou
```

The string "/SignUpFor" returns a match on the first expression which is correct; the string "/SignUpFor/ThankYou" returns a match on both.

How can I get "SignUpFor/ThankYou" just to match with the expression `/SignUpFor/ThankYou`.

The reason I'm not just using "==" is that I have other expressions such as `/TheLovelyBlog/Entry/([0-9]+)`

These expression are stored in a database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

put a ^ at the start and a $ at the end
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Add **^** and **$** in the beginning and in the end of your expressions

Comment: @user415394: if answers helped you, you should accept kmcc049's answer (he was first to it)

Comment: @user415394: use the big green check mark to the left of the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you start a regex with `^`, then the match must be from the start.
End the regex with `$` to signal that the match must be until the end.